# Searching a file with input from another file in python

Tags: python, file

What I am trying to do is read a line from one file to a string, then search another file for the line that contains that string and parse that line with `.split()`.

My code looks like this:

```
for line in portslist:
    marker = line.split()
    printername = marker[0]
    address = marker[1]

    for lines in constantfile:
        if address in line: #if the desired address is in the line
            lineholder = line
            lineholder = lineholder.split()
            oldonline = lineholder[4]
            oldutc = lineholder[5]
            status = lineholder[2]
```

However, I get the error

```
in readermain oldonline=lineholder[4] IndexError: list index out of range
```

After some trouble shooting it appears that the line from my constantfile is never being assigned to line. Instead it seems the line from the file portlist is being assigned to line, which only has an index of two.

My question is how to make the line that the string `"address"` is in assigned to line so I can parse and use it?

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect - that Python file wouldn't even run. Could you check and fix it?

Comment: Also, what exactly are `portslist` and `constantfile`?

Comment: Sorry about the indentation. It didn't copy over correctly. It is correct in my actual code however. As for portslist and constantfile, they are both files opened elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using `line` where you should be using `lines`:

```
for lines in constantfile:
    if address in lines: #if the desired address is in the line
        lineholder=lines.split()
        # etc.
```

Also, if `constantfile` is a file object, that iterator will be exhausted after the first pass of the outer `for` loop.

Comment: `constantfile` is indeed a file object. How would I avoid the outer iterator being exhausted after the first pass? This is my first real python program so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could read both of them into lists; then you can iterate over them as often as you like: `constantfile = open(filename).readlines()` etc.

Comment: So I have changed `line` to `lines` and made both `constantfile` and `portslist` into lists using your advice. The problem I have now is that it just keeps reading the first line from constantfile over and over again. I'm pretty sure this still has something to do with the iteration?

Comment: Perhaps you could open another question and post your code there? This looks like a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation makes it so that even if "address in line" evaluates false, the rest of the block will run.

Second, the line from constantfile should assign to variable "lines".  Reword the corresponding code to

```
if address in lines:
    lineholder = lines
    ...
```

and you should be good.

Furthermore, I would suggest a less arbitrary naming convention that makes it explicit that you are dealing with lines from 2 different files.  For example

- line -> portline
- marker -> portlinesplit
- lines -> constline
- lineholder -> constlinesplit

That way it would be less confusing, and your code would be more readable.